# mandatory radio button checked in form not working

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button, required-field

I have been at this for well over an hour and searched here and on the Web for an answer, but can't get this to work, so I am now asking for some help please.

I have a form where all fields are mandatory to be filled, including a "Radio" button to be selected, the radio button group called "instrument".

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkFields(f) {
        name1 = document.form1.name1.value;
        name2 = document.form1.name2.value;
        email1 = document.form1.email1.value;
        instrument = document.form1.instrument.value;
        stylemusic = document.form1.stylemusic.value;

        if ((name1 == "") || (name2 == "") || (email1 == "") || (instrument == "") || (stylemusic == "")) {
            alert("All fields need to be filled.");
            return false;
        }
}
```

and my form code:

```
<input type="radio" value="percussion" name="instrument">Percussion
<input type="radio" value="wind" name="instrument">Wind
```

Comment: What is the value of instrument when no button is selected?

Comment: @demize there isn't a default value. One of the radio buttons "must" be clicked in order for the form to continue.

Comment: I know there's no default value, I meant when no button is selected what would be the output of something like `echo instrument` (I don't know much about Javascript, so I can't really test it myself, I would if I could because I'm interested in why this doesn't work.) Maybe you need to use `null` or something similar instead of a null string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found my answer** and am posting it here, in case someone is faced with the same problem:

```
if((document.form1.instrument[0].checked==false)&&(document.form1.instrument[1].checked==false))

{
alert('You must make a choice');
return false
}
```

**Note**: Add another instance of [2], [3] etc in order to accomodate for more radio button choices.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use validation against radio buttons, just make one of your radio buttons checked by default, this way, you'll be sure that every group has a checked button.

This accomplishes two things:

- Required groups are checked
- No need to javascript validation

Of course, I'm assuming that you are using groups, radio buttons don't make sense individually, they need to be grouped.

Comment: That would work, but it's normally better to make sure that the user input what they wanted than the random value that was preselected.

Comment: @Soufiane Hassou The radio button in the form must be selected. I don't want the form to be executed if a radio button is not clicked.